# Deleting strange directories in unix

Tags: unix, quotes, rm

I am having some issues deleting some folders in unix.

Directory 1:

```
?0\'
```

Directory 2:

```
-1\'
```

I would like to delete them recursively so something like

`rm -rf -1\'`

Not sure on how to escape the quotes, dashes and question marks.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: How do I delete a folder with the name ?0\' and -1\'

Comment: You can use midnight commander (`mc` command) or any other graphic/pseudographic  file browser.

Comment: In a related problem, if you have files with names with unprintable characters etc., you may have no choice but to use `rm -i *` to step through every file in the directory and answer y/n if you want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes when they are fishy characters, then use a wildcard outside of the quotes. Without quotes those characters would want to preform other tasks.

```
rm -rf -- *"\'"
```

Thanks to a comment by osgx

Comment: also, it can be useful to add `--` after `-rf` to say: there will be no any option after `--` even if it looks like option. So, full answer (based on your variant): `rm -rf -- *"\'"`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful; check carefully before you execute any `rm -fr` on weird directory names.

The standard trick for file names (directory names) starting with a dash `-` is to prefix the name with `./` so that it doesn't start with `-` any more:

```
rm -fr ./-1??
```

The other directory could perhaps be identified by:

```
rm -fr ./?0??
```

I would, at the very least, run:

```
echo ./-1?? ./?0??
```

before trying the `rm` commands, to ensure that only the correct directories are picked up.  The `rm` command is dangerous if you're not certain that it is doing what you want.

The notation using questions marks avoids having to quote the question marks, backslashes and single quotes, in part out of a suspicion that what shows on the terminal may not be the name in the file system.  You may need to do further work to identify the names, such `ls | od -c` or similar commands to validate the exact spelling of the directory names.